# Transposing a string

Tags: ruby, string

Given a (multiline) string, where each line is separated by `"\n"` and may not be necessarily of the same length, what is the best way to transpose it into another string as follows? Lines shorter than the longest one should be padded with space (right padding in terms of the original, or bottom padding in terms of the output). Applying the operation on a string twice should be idempotent modulo padding.

**Input string**

```
abc
def ghi
jk lm no
```

**Output string**

```
adj
bek
cf 
  l
 gm
 h 
 in
  o
```

Comment: the characters "\n" or an actual new line, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are five approaches.  (Yes, I got a bit carried away, but I find that trying to think of different ways to accomplish the same task is good exercise for the grey cells.)

**#1**

An uninteresting, brute-force method:

```
a = str.split("\n")
l = a.max_by(&:size).size
puts a.map { |b| b.ljust(l).chars }
      .transpose
      .map { |c| c.join.rstrip }.join("\n")
adj
bek
cf
  l
 gm
 h
 in
  o
```

**#2**

This method and all that follow avoid the use of `ljust` and `transpose`, and make use of the fact that if `e` is an empty array, `e.shift` returns `nil` and leaves `e` an empty array.  (Aside: I am often reaching for the non-existent method `String#shift`.  Here it would have avoided the need to convert each line to an array of characters.)

```
a = str.split("\n").map(&:chars)
a.max_by(&:size).size.times.map { a.map { |e| e.shift || ' ' }.join.rstrip }
```

**#3**

This and the remaining methods avoid the need to compute the length of the longest string:

```
a = str.split("\n").map(&:chars)
a_empty = Array(a.size, [])
[].tap { |b| b << a.map { |e| e.shift || ' ' }.join.rstrip while a != a_empty }
```

**#4**

This method makes use of [Enumerator#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-lazy), which has been available since v2.0.

```
a = str.split("\n").map(&:chars)
(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map do |i|
  a.each { |e| e.shift } if i > 0 
  a.map  { |e| e.first || ' ' }.join.rstrip
end.take_while { c = a.any? { |e| !e.empty? }  }.to_a
```

(I initially had a problem getting this to work, as I was not getting the element of the output (`"  o"`).  The fix was adding the third line and changing the line that follows from `a.map { |e| e.shift || ' ' }.join.rstrip` to what I have now.  I mention this because it seems like it may be common problem when using `lazy`.)

**#5**

Lastly, use recursion:

```
def recurse(a, b=[])
  return b[0..-2] if a.last.empty?
  b << a.map { |e| e.shift || ' ' }.join.rstrip
  recurse(a, b)
end

a = str.split("\n").map(&:chars)
recurse(a)
```

Comment: Solution #2 fails for this simple test:
```ruby
def test_two_characters_in_a_column
    input = "A\n1"
    expected = "A1"
    assert_equal expected, Transpose.transpose(input)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```ruby
def transpose s
  lines = s.split(?\n)
  longest = lines.map { |l| l.length }.max

  (0..longest).map do |index|
    lines.map { |l| l[index] || ' ' }.join
  end * ?\n
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works

```
s = "abc\ndef ghi\njk lm no\n"

s = s.split("\n")
s2 = ''
i = 0
while true
  line = ''
  s.each do |row|
    line += (row[i] or ' ')
  end

  if line.strip == ''
    break
  end

  s2 += line + "\n"
  i += 1
end

puts s2
```

This one also works

```
s = "abc\ndef ghi\njk lm no\n"

s = s.split("\n")
maxlen = s.inject(0) {|m,r| m=[m, r.length].max}
s.map! {|r| r.ljust(maxlen).split(//)}
s = s.transpose.map {|r| r.join('')}.join("\n")

puts s
```

Comment: @sawa, it's fixed and added another one

Comment: Just a couple of minor points: 1. `r.join('')` and be written 'r.join` and `r.join.rstrip` is needed if to eliminate trailing spaces, if that's desired (e.g., if `" h"` rather than `" h "`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for the tips. They are very educational.

Answer (score 0):

A play on what [Chron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818463/) did for an earlier version of ruby (e.g., 1.8.x).  [Example](http://codepad.org/4gYiEOig) *based on your original input that showed newline characters*

```
str="abc\\n
def ghi\\n
jk lm no\\n"


def transpose s
  lines = s.gsub("\\n","").split("\n")
  longest = lines.map { |line| line.length }.max

  (0..longest).map do |char_index|
    lines.map { |line| line.split('')[char_index] || ' ' }.join
  end * "\\n\n"
end

puts transpose(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
def transpose_text(text)
  # split the text into lines
  text = text.split("\n")

  # find the length of the longest line
  max_line_length = text.map(&:size).max

  # pad each line with white space and convert them to character arrays
  text.map! { |line| line.ljust(max_line_length).chars }

  #transpose the character arrays and then join them all into one string
  text.transpose.map(&:join).join("\n")
end
```